# JSON Query for import.io

Tags: json, import.io

I'm using import.io and trying to figure out how to write a code that that uses multiple inputs to run a connector query. I've never used JSON before but essentially what I'm trying to do is to expand this existing query:

```
{
    "input": {
        "name": "Marin Academy",
        "city": "San Rafael"
    },
}
```

To include multiple names. So that when I run the query, IO automatically searches a list of organizations. What would be the correct syntax to achieve this?

I tried

```
{
    "input": {
        "name": "Marin Academy",
        "city": "San Rafael"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mt. Hood Community College",
        "city": "Gresham"
    }
}
```

But it gives me a syntax error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of an an array, please use **square brackets before the beginning and after the end of curly brackets** like...

```
{
    "input": [
      {
        "name": "Marin Academy",
        "city": "San Rafael"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mt. Hood Community College",
        "city": "Gresham"
      }
    ]
}
```

This will solve the JSON sytax error at least.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Import.io says "Bad JSON Input" so I assume they don't allow multiple input queries. Thanks anyways, Prateek!

Comment: @New2JSON Ok :) Please select this as answer and upvote if it helped solve your doubt/issue :)

Comment: @New2JSON Thanks :)